# Illegal instruction (core dumped) when trying to execute elf file

Tags: linux, gnu, elf

I am trying to execute a elf file (call it precompiled) and it gives:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Compiling from source works fine

```
gcc source.c
./a.out
```

Debug info:

```
file precompiled
precompiled: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=<BUILD ID HERE>, not stripped
file a
a: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=<BUILD ID HERE>, not stripped
```

What can be causing this error? If it is the different GNU/Linux version, how can I download from the terminal the necessary packages?

Comment: Please state the name and show the source code or disassembly of the misbehaving program or library.

Answer (score 0):

It means the compiled binary contains an instruction(possibly more than one instruction) that's not valid on the architecture where you're running it.

You can run your binary under `gdb` to find out specific instruction:

```
gdb ./precompiled
(gdb) run
(gdb) bt
(gdb) disassemble
```

Then type `run` and then when it fails, run `bt` (backtrace) to see where it fails. Use `disassemble` to see the specific instruction that's causing the failure.

There's not much you can do to fix it. You could potentially edit the binary by disassembling it and editing the assembly and again compiling it into a binary. Given that you have the source code, it's simpler to re-compile on your target machine.

You may be able to avoid specific instructions (when compiling on a different machine -- where you compiled `precompiled` binary) by using compiler switches based on your target architecture.

Comment: is there any way to detect what architecture?

Comment: It's the machine where you run your binary on. `/proc/cpuinfo` has the information on whether a particular feature is supported by your cpu.